# strotime() returning false on proper date formatted string?

Tags: php

Trying to format a date string using a technique I've used countless times, suddenly returning false (PHP5). Anyone run into this?

```
//$new_date = June 14,2010
echo $new_date;
$new_date = date("F j, Y", strtotime($new_date));
//returns the infamous December 31, 1969 because strototime() is returning false?
```

Comment: Cannot replicate. What OS and locale?

Comment: Cannot replicate. *Precisely* which PHP version are you using? Are you *sure* the original `$new_date` has that value?

Comment: Replicating previous comments regarding inability to replicate. Uncomment first line in your code.

Comment: Replication of previous replication about not being to replicate. Even heavy locale adjustments don't throw it out of whack. Hidden parts in the actual string perhaps? (non-printable characters, html-tags not showing up in browser when just doing echo)

Answer (score 0):

```
Type of string               |           REGEX                  |   EXAMPLE
Textual month, day and year  | m ([ .\t-])* dd [,.stndrh\t ]+ y | "July 1st, 2008", "April 17, 1790", "May.9,78"
```

Taken from http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php

`strtotime` should work for the date you specified.  Make sure the date going into your function is really in the format m d,y